# parametrization of body jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, quality-assurance

I just started using Jmeter and don't know how to make a variable. This is the HTTP body request and I would like to change the project name each time I perform load testing.
[image: body data]

I tried using CSV config but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file which looks like

```
project x
project y
project z
```

1. Add a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and:

   - provide full or relative path to the CSV file, i.e. `projects.csv`
   - desired variable name, i.e. `project`

   [image]
2. Once done you will be able to refer the value from the CSV as `${project}` where required, i.e. in the Body Data tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

   [image]
3. When you run your test the `${project}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholder will be replaced by the next line from the CSV file on each iteration of each virtual user:

   [image]

More information: [JMeter Parameterization: The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization)

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the body in JMeter by using the following steps:

1 Add a "HTTP Request" sampler to your test plan

2 In the Body Data section of the HTTP Request sampler, use variables to define the content of the request body. For example, if you want to send a JSON payload, you can write it like this:

```
{
   "username":"${username}",
   "password":"${password}"
}
```

3 To define the values of the variables, you can use a "CSV Data Set Config" element.

4 In the CSV Data Set Config element, specify the file name and other details of the CSV file containing the data.

5 Reference the variables in the HTTP Request sampler using the syntax `${variable_name}`

For more detailed information, you can refer to the following resources:

1. JMeter User Manual - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html
2. JMeter - How to Use CSV Data Set Config - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
3. How to Parameterize Requests in JMeter - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-parameterize-requests-in-jmeter/